# selecting the nth column

Tags: awk, sed

printing nth column and removing some extra characters

> cat test.log
>
> 12-22-2018-00.log:[1545418720] SERVER ALERT: irqz1;response from
>   Server(in ms) : 387
>
> 12-22-2018-00.log:[1545118720] PING ALERT: irqz2;Server is up since
>   902 days

`grep -i 'SERVER' test.log |awk '{print $1,$NF}'`

```
12-22-2018-00.log:[1545418720] 387
```

`grep -i 'PING' test.log |awk '{print $1,$NF-1}'`

```
12-22-2018-00.log:[1545118720] 902
```

Actual result i want is:

```
Server 1545418720 387
Ping   1545118720 902
```

So in case of Server alert it will select the unix timestamp and the last column and in case of ping alert, it will select unix timestamp and 2nd to the right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(GNU `awk`).

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/server alert/{gsub(/.*\[|\]$/,"",$1);print $1,$NF;next} /ping alert/{gsub(/.*\[|\]$/,"",$1);print $1,$(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /server alert/{gsub(/.*\[|\]$/,"",$1);print $1,$NF}' Input_file
AND
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /ping alert/{gsub(/.*\[|\]$/,"",$1);print $1,$(NF-1)}' Input_file
```